# Is ASP.NET HttpPostedFile.SaveAs a blocking call?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering whether `HttpPostedFile.SaveAs` function in ASP.NET C# is a blocking call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes (snippet from reflector):

```
FileStream s = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
try
{
    this._stream.WriteTo(s);
    s.Flush();
}
finally
{
    s.Close();
}
```

It does not use `BeginWrite` and `EndWrite` so it is blocking.

---

### UPDATE

If you are wondering what `_stream.WriteTo(s);` does:

```
internal void WriteTo(Stream s)
{
    if ((this._data != null) && (this._length > 0))
    {
        this._data.WriteBytes(this._offset, this._length, s);
    }
}
```

which is again blocking.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have enough rep to vote you up tho. Soon enough :)